# change date if it is a weekend javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to change date if it is a weekend to a Monday, but it does not work when I try to proceed. I'm a very to javascript.

With some help, I managed to do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getdate()
 {
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
     items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i+1)).value;
 }



for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
{
    items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i+1)).value;
    var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
    var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
    if (itemDt.getDay() == 6 || itemDt.getDay() == 0) {
      alert('weekend!');
      setDate(itemDt.getDate() + 2);
    }
}
 return items;
 }
 </script>
```

but it displays to me some errors. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the isWeekend jQuery plugin?

Comment: Actually this plugin is not adapted for myself because I will add more days like holly days and new years days chrismats days and days off in France 

The mistake I have is Uncaught ReferenceError: setDate is not defined

Answer (score 1):

`setDate()` is a `Date` function. Thus, you need to invoke it on a `Date` object:

```
itemDt.setDate(itemDt.getDate() + 2);
```

However, since you need a list of strings instead, you can use the following:

```
function formatDate(dt) {
  var day = dt.getDate();
  var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
  return [day < 10 ? "0" + day : day, 
          month < 10 ? "0" + month : month, 
          dt.getFullYear()].join('-');
}

function getdate() {
  var items = [];
  var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
  for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
    var dateValue = document.getElementById("date" + (i+1)).value;        
    var itemDtParts = dateValue.split("-");
    var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
    var day = itemDt.getDay();
    itemDt.setDate(itemDt.getDate() + (day == 6 ? 2 : day == 0 ? 1 : 0));
    items.push(formatDate(itemDt));
  }
  return items;
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54xtc/)**.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually it does not show any error report but dates are still remain the same

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Do you want to return an array of elements of type `Date`? Or just the strings?

Comment: In fact all of my elements are display in buton forms. It comes from the query of mysql . All is displayed in forms using while data=mysql_fetch_asssoc($result), I just would like to change dhis dates by monday in the fomr input date fields

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to return from `getdate()`? A list of date strings where weekends are shift by 2 days?

Comment: In fact I have date from getdate From input I just want to replace the dates that are weekend by the next monday because In my country unfortunately, weekends are days off and nobody wants to work

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: I see, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: You forgot the HTML part. Also you don't need to replicate all that code. Just copy the `formatDate` function above.

Comment: it is like that <input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][date]" class="date" id="date<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php 


echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['date_action'])) ;

 ?>" size="12">